# How to indent TOC-entries (as indexes) which have no numbers with tocbasic?

Tags: koma-script, tocbasic

Similar to [this question here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8KYF.png), how can I indent the `chapter*`-like entries to the same indent as the numbered chapters?
`section*` work with `\KOMAoptions{toc=indentunnumbered}`.

The main difference to the other questions concerning indent with unnumbered chapter is related to indexes: The indentation of indexes won’t work with `\addchap`/`\addsec` etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman,twoside=false,listof=totoc,listof=leveldown]{scrbook}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[style=archaeologie]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{archaeologie-examples.bib}
\usepackage{babel}
\newcommand\tocgobble[1]{}% <- added
\newcommand\tocpageseparator{\footnotesize\,\mbox{---}\,}
\newcommand\tocpagenumberbox[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\KOMAoptions{toc=indentunnumbered}%indent only for section* !?

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocraggedpagenumber,
  toclinefill=\tocpageseparator,
  tocindent=0em,
  tocnumwidth=4em,
  tocpagenumberbox=\tocpagenumberbox
]{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocentryformat=\large\scshape,
  tocindent=0em,
  tocnumwidth=4em,
  tocpagenumberbox=\tocgobble
]{part}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  tocentryformat=\textbf%
]{chapter}

\makeindex[
  intoc,
  name=loc, 
  title={Locations},
  columns=3,
  ]
\indexsetup{%
  level=\section*,
  toclevel=section,
  noclearpage,
  firstpagestyle=scrheadings,
  headers={\indexname}{\indexname},
    }
\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \frontmatter
  \tableofcontents
  \mainmatter
  \part{part}
  \chapter{chapter chapter}
  \section{section section section}  \section{section section section}  \section{section section section}
  \part{part}
  \chapter{chapter chapter}
  \section{section section section}  \section{section section section}  \section{section section section}
  \setcounter{page}{100}
  \part{part}
  \chapter{chapter chapter}
  \section{section section section}  \section{section section section}  \section{section section section}
  \backmatter

  \part{part}
\index[loc]{A location}
  \chapter*{Abbildungs-, Tabellen-, Tafelverzeichnis}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbildungs-, Tabellen-, Tafelverzeichnis}
  \listoffigures
  \chapter*{\bibname}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
  \printbiblist[%
      heading=subbibintoc,%
    title={Zeitschriftenabkürzungen}]{shortjournal}
  \printbiblist[%
    heading=subbibintoc,%
    title={Reihenabkürzungen}]{shortseries}
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]
\chapter*{Indizes}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Indizes}
\printindex[loc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you thought about using the right commands? You apparently have not read the KOMA documentation -> `\addchap{Indizes}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your claim is wrong. You are just using the wrong commands.

[image: lukasKomaIndentunnumbered]

```
\documentclass[ngerman,twoside=false,listof=totoc,listof=leveldown]{scrbook}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\KOMAoptions{toc=indentunnumbered}%indent only for section* !?
\makeindex[
  name=loc, 
  title={Locations},
  columns=3,
  ]
\indexsetup{%
  level=\addsec,
  noclearpage,
  headers={\indexname}{\indexname},
    }
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
\chapter{Wombat}
\index[loc]{A location}
\section{Walter}
\addchap{Capybara}
\addsec{Carl}
\chapter*{Lion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lion}% Not the KOMA way
\section*{Laura}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Laura}% Not the KOMA way
\addchap{Indizes}
\printindex[loc]
\end{document}
```

---

Note, that the `\add<level>` commands are only defined for `part`, `chapter` and `section` level.

The section commands of  all KOMA-Script classes uses command `\addxcontentsline` (provided by package `tocbasic`) instead of `\addcontentsline`. The macro `\addxcontentsline` knows an additional optional argument:

```
\addxcontentsline{<extension>}{<level>}[<number>]{<text>}
```

Option `toc=indentunnumbered` requires the usage `\addxcontentsline`!

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{toc=indentunnumbered}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\addchap{Unnumbered chapter}
\addsec{Unnumbered section}
\subsection*{Unnumbered subsection%
  \addxcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Unnumbered section}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, I can adjust `chapter` and `section` with `\addchap`/`addsec`, but it won’t work with `makeindex`. Any idea for that?

Comment: @LukasCB Please adjust the minimal working example in your question to produce an index.

Comment: it is! isn’t it?

Comment: @LukasCB Yes, sorry. Your example is far to complex. But i still don't see, why it wouldn't work with makeindex?

Comment: I found my error - havn’t thinking of `level=\addsec` etc. Thanks for helping!