# Modify List of Figures and Tables

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, koma-script

I am writing my thesis and have some issues with my List of Figures and List of Tables. I want them to look like my Table of Contents (which I have from here: [How to indent TOC-entries (as indexes) which have no numbers with tocbasic?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417074/)).
I have used tocstyle, which is not working anymore.

Code so far:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt,bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\newcommand\tocpageseparator{\hspace{1em}\,}
\newcommand\tocpagenumberbox[1]{\mbox{#1}}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
tocraggedpagenumber,
toclinefill=\tocpageseparator,
tocnumwidth=3em,
tocpagenumberbox=\tocpagenumberbox
]{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Section one}

\begin{figure}
    A Figure
    \caption{Figure one - A Figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

My List of Figures (and Tables) looks like this:
[image: LoF]

And I want both to look like this, regarding dots, spacing between caption and page number:
[image: ToC]

I hope you can help me with my issue. If it is relevant, I am using KOMA-Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[...]{tocline}{figure,table}` with the same options as for `chapter,section,...` but without the prefix `toc`:

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
    raggedpagenumber,
    linefill=\tocpageseparator,
    numwidth=3em,
    pagenumberbox=\tocpagenumberbox
  ]{tocline}{figure,table}
```

Note that you can use this command for `chapter,section,...` entries too:

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
    raggedpagenumber,
    linefill=\tocpageseparator,
    numwidth=3em,
    pagenumberbox=\tocpagenumberbox
  ]{tocline}{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,figure,table}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside,11pt,bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% needed with outdated TeX distributions
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\newcommand\tocpageseparator{\hspace{1em}\,}
\newcommand\tocpagenumberbox[1]{\mbox{#1}}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
    raggedpagenumber,
    linefill=\tocpageseparator,
    numwidth=3em,
    pagenumberbox=\tocpagenumberbox
  ]{tocline}{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,figure,table}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Section one}

\begin{figure}
    A Figure
    \caption{Figure one - A Figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much :)